# @Formula of enum type causes ClassCastException in Hibernate 4.2.8.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, formula

I'm trying to map a `@Formula` to an enum value in **Hibernate 4.2.8.Final**.

However, I encounter the following ClassCastException:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.Formula cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Column
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createParameterImpl(SimpleValue.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.testing.junit4.BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase.buildSessionFactory(BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.testing.junit4.TestClassMetadata.performCallbackInvocation(TestClassMetadata.java:205)
    ... 15 more
```

This is my code:

```
// Read-only property
private FooBarEnum foo = FooBarEnum.DEFAULT;

// Calculate value of property
@Formula("(SELECT MIN(A.foobar) AS MIN_FOO FROM table_b B JOIN table_a A ON B.fk_bar=A.id WHERE B.id=id)")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public FooBarEnum getFooBarEnum() {
    return this.foo;
}
```

I found [this bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9369) which describes the exact same problem. The bug is fixed, however I cannot update to 4.2.16+.

**Is there any workaround I can apply to make my `@Formula` and enum getter work on Hibernate 4.2.8.Final?**

This is the faulty code in Hibernate:

```
private void createParameterImpl() {
  try {
    String[] columnsNames = new String[columns.size()];
    for ( int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++ ) {
      columnsNames[i] = ( (Column) columns.get( i ) ).getName(); // <- This cast fails
    }

    ...
```